# ThymeLeaf 3.0 + Spring - th:include gives FileNotFoundException

Tags: thymeleaf

I am new to ThymeLeaf. Am using ThymeLeaf 3.0 + Spring. Need to create email templates. Am using SpringResourceTemplateResolver. Have done a simple include as below:

```
<div th:include="emailContent"></div>
```

The emailContent.html file is as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div>
    © 2011 The Good Thymes Virtual Grocery 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This file is present in the correct folder that the parent file is present in.

```
Latitude-3450:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/recruitment/WEB-INF/classes/emailtemplates$ ls -altr emailContent.html 
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat7 tomcat7 108 May 30 09:31 emailContent.html
```

However the include cause the exception below:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/emailtemplates/emailContent] 
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141) 
        at org.thymeleaf.spring3.templateresource.SpringResourceTemplateResource.reader(SpringResourceTemplateResource.java:103) 
        at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:223)
```

Without the include I get the email correctly with the parent file.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Question answered at http://forum.thymeleaf.org/ThymeLeaf-3-0-th-include-gives-FileNotFoundException-td4029712.html

Comment: In my case I forgot set resolver suffix resolver.setSuffix(".html");